# How to show Matplotlib graph in VS Code?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I'm following a Python tutorial book I have (Python Crash Course 2nd Edition) and I'm currently doing Project 2, where they teach about visually representing data with things such as Matplotlib. Unfortunately, the code I run (which is the same as the code in the book) doesn't make a graph show up anywhere.

The book I'm following expects you to be running the code in Sublime Text, while I'm running it in VS Code, so I originally thought that maybe Sublime would show the graph automatically, but it doesn't when I tried to run the code over there.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(squares)

plt.show()
```

And I have installed matplotlib in the terminal, using this command:

```
$ python -m pip install --user matplotlib
```

The book I'm following says that, "The function `plt.show()` opens Matplotlib's viewer and displays the plot as shown in Figure 15-1. The viewer allows you to zoom and navigate the plot, and when you click the disk icon, you can save any plot images you like." Figure 15-1 shows a graph with the various different points connected with lines. And remember, even running the code on Sublime doesn't make the Matplotlib viewer show up.

I'm on Windows 11. VS is using Python 3.10.8, while I have Python 3.12 installed on my laptop (I don't know how to update this on VS though).

Comment: In the lower right corner of VS Code, you should see the Python interpreter that's currently being used. I believe if you click that you can change which interpreter it uses to run your programs. It would be helpful to know what OS you are running as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mind using [Jupyter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) to run your Matplotlib Python code.

You can install [jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) in extension store.

Then create a `.ipynb` file and choose the python kernel. Running your python codes in the Jupyter cell may be more intuitive and convenient.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works on my computer in VS Code. Could you please try the following, to find out, what version of python your are using?

1. Open the terminal in visual studio code and type

   python

followed by enter.

2. Something like the following should show up inside the terminal:

   Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02)
   [Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

   > > > 
3. Check if you have a different version of python on your PC as well. Open a second terminal and type

   python3

followed by enter.

Are the versions of python the same?

Maybe you installed matplotlib not for all version. I can not recommend multiple versions of python as a beginner. If you haven't installed matplotlib in the version of python you are using, you should get an error from your code in VS Code. But this is not the case or?

Another try:
You can test your code directly in the terminal:

4. Open python in the terminal via "python3" or "python".
5. Paste all your code from your question into the terminal and press enter. Does this work?

I would like to help, if you could give more information.

Comment: I entered Python to the terminal, and it says this:                                                                                                                             `Python 3.10.8 (main, Oct 17 2023, 22:43:19) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.` On my computer, I have Python v3.12 installed, while VS Code has 3.10.8 installed. Do you know how I can update the Python version I'm using on VS?

Comment: I also put the code in the terminal and ran it, but I just got a bunch of nonsense that I can't understand (and no graph showed up). Also, I don't get an error when I run the code in VS, it's just that nothing happens.

Comment: Could you post the feedback of your terminal, when you entered your code there?

Answer (score 0):

I think VS Code would handle it great if you put the code into a GUI framework like tkinter. Here is a sample of something I did while showing color palettes. I am not an expert in Python so there may be some inefficiencies, but it should run with Python 3.12.2. This is a hack together of samples from

https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html#colormaps

and

https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-matplotlib/

```
from colorspacious import cspace_converter

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import matplotlib as mpl

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2Tk

import tkinter as tk


cmaps = {}
mpl.use('TkAgg')

gradient = np.linspace(0, 1, 256)
gradient = np.vstack((gradient, gradient))

def plot_color_gradients(category, cmap_list):
    # Create figure and adjust figure height to number of colormaps
    nrows = len(cmap_list)
    figh = 0.35 + 0.15 + (nrows + (nrows - 1) * 0.1) * 0.22
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows + 1, figsize=(6.4, figh))
    fig.subplots_adjust(top=1 - 0.35 / figh, bottom=0.15 / figh,
                        left=0.2, right=0.99)
    axs[0].set_title(f'{category} colormaps', fontsize=14)

    for ax, name in zip(axs, cmap_list):
        ax.imshow(gradient, aspect='auto', cmap=mpl.colormaps[name])
        ax.text(-0.01, 0.5, name, va='center', ha='right', fontsize=10,
                transform=ax.transAxes)

    # Turn off *all* ticks & spines, not just the ones with colormaps.
    for ax in axs:
        ax.set_axis_off()

    # Save colormap list for later.
    cmaps[category] = cmap_list
    return fig

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Color Palette Exploration')
        self.geometry('300x150')

        fig = plot_color_gradients('Perceptually Uniform Sequential',['viridis', 'plasma', 'inferno', 'magma', 'cividis'])

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,self)
 
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=App()
    app.mainloop()
```